# AWK- replace values on specific ranges with strings

Tags: awk

I have a column named "Diff" ($11) which is the final difference between 2 teams on a game.

I have lots of values so I would like to simplify the reading for the user.

Let say that If the difference is higher than -20, the value should be replaced with "big loss".  If it's between -19 and -5, replace with "loss". If it's between -4 and -1, replace with "close loss"

And the same logic but with positive numbers (close win, win, big win).

I think I know who to do it in bash but AWK is something new to me (I need it in AWK).

In bash I think it could be:

```
IFS=',' records=() sorted=()
{ 
    IFS='' read -r header

    while read -r -a values
    do

        case ${values[11]} in
            (${values[11]}>-20)) values[11]=Big Loss ;;
            (-20>${values[11]}>-5)) values[11]=Loss ;;
            (-5>${values[11]}>0)) values[11]=Close Loss ;;
            (${values[11]}>20)) values[11]=Big Win ;;
            (20>${values[11]}>5)) values[11]=Win ;;
            (5>${values[11]}>0))) values[11]=Close Win ;;
    done
```

Some input data:

```
    EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc
    1985,1,1,10/26/1984,21,252,21.6899384,CHI,1,WSB,1,16,1,40,5,16,0.313,0,0,,6,7,0.857,1,5,6,7,2,4,5,2,16,12.5
    1985,2,2,10/27/1984,21,253,21.69267625,CHI,0,MIL,0,-2,1,34,8,13,0.615,0,0,,5,5,1,3,2,5,5,2,1,3,4,21,19.4
    1985,3,3,10/29/1984,21,255,21.69815195,CHI,1,MIL,1,6,1,34,13,24,0.542,0,0,,11,13,0.846,2,2,4,5,6,2,3,4,37,32.9
    1985,4,4,10/30/1984,21,256,21.7008898,CHI,0,KCK,1,5,1,36,8,21,0.381,0,0,,9,9,1,2,2,4,5,3,1,6,5,25,14.7
    1985,5,5,11/1/1984,21,258,21.7063655,CHI,0,DEN,0,-16,1,33,7,15,0.467,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,2,5,5,1,1,2,4,17,13.2
    1985,6,6,11/7/1984,21,264,21.72279261,CHI,0,DET,1,4,1,27,9,19,0.474,0,0,,7,9,0.778,1,3,4,3,3,1,5,5,25,14.9
    1985,7,7,11/8/1984,21,265,21.72553046,CHI,0,NYK,1,15,1,33,15,22,0.682,0,0,,3,4,0.75,4,4,8,5,3,2,5,2,33,29.3
    1985,8,8,11/10/1984,21,267,21.73100616,CHI,0,IND,1,2,1,42,9,22,0.409,0,0,,9,12,0.75,2,7,9,4,2,5,3,4,27,21.2
    1985,9,9,11/13/1984,21,270,21.73921971,CHI,1,SAS,1,3,1,43,18,27,0.667,1,1,1,8,11,0.727,2,8,10,4,3,2,4,4,45,37.5
    1985,10,10,11/15/1984,21,272,21.74469541,CHI,1,BOS,0,-20,1,33,12,24,0.5,0,1,0,3,3,1,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,4,27,17.1
    1985,11,11,11/17/1984,21,274,21.75017112,CHI,1,PHI,0,-9,1,44,4,17,0.235,0,0,,8,8,1,0,5,5,7,5,2,4,5,16,12.5
    1985,12,12,11/19/1984,21,276,21.75564682,CHI,1,IND,0,-17,1,39,11,26,0.423,0,3,0,12,16,0.75,2,3,5,2,2,1,3,3,34,20.8
    1985,13,13,11/21/1984,21,278,21.76112252,CHI,0,MIL,0,-10,1,42,11,22,0.5,0,0,,13,14,0.929,4,9,13,2,2,2,6,3,35,26.7
    1985,14,14,11/23/1984,21,280,21.76659822,CHI,0,SEA,1,19,1,30,9,13,0.692,0,0,,5,6,0.833,0,4,4,3,4,1,4,4,23,19.5
    1985,15,15,11/24/1984,21,281,21.76933607,CHI,0,POR,0,-10,1,41,10,24,0.417,0,1,0,10,10,1,3,3,6,8,3,1,4,4,30,23.9
```

Expected output:

```
 EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc
    1985,1,1,10/26/1984,21,252,21.6899384,CHI,1,WSB,1,Win,1,40,5,16,0.313,0,0,,6,7,0.857,1,5,6,7,2,4,5,2,16,12.5
    1985,2,2,10/27/1984,21,253,21.69267625,CHI,0,MIL,0,Close Loss,1,34,8,13,0.615,0,0,,5,5,1,3,2,5,5,2,1,3,4,21,19.4
    1985,3,3,10/29/1984,21,255,21.69815195,CHI,1,MIL,1,Win,1,34,13,24,0.542,0,0,,11,13,0.846,2,2,4,5,6,2,3,4,37,32.9
    1985,4,4,10/30/1984,21,256,21.7008898,CHI,0,KCK,1,Win,1,36,8,21,0.381,0,0,,9,9,1,2,2,4,5,3,1,6,5,25,14.7
    1985,5,5,11/1/1984,21,258,21.7063655,CHI,0,DEN,0,Loss,1,33,7,15,0.467,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,2,5,5,1,1,2,4,17,13.2
    1985,6,6,11/7/1984,21,264,21.72279261,CHI,0,DET,1,Close Win,1,27,9,19,0.474,0,0,,7,9,0.778,1,3,4,3,3,1,5,5,25,14.9
    1985,7,7,11/8/1984,21,265,21.72553046,CHI,0,NYK,1,Win,1,33,15,22,0.682,0,0,,3,4,0.75,4,4,8,5,3,2,5,2,33,29.3
    1985,8,8,11/10/1984,21,267,21.73100616,CHI,0,IND,1,Close Win,1,42,9,22,0.409,0,0,,9,12,0.75,2,7,9,4,2,5,3,4,27,21.2
    1985,9,9,11/13/1984,21,270,21.73921971,CHI,1,SAS,1,Close Win,1,43,18,27,0.667,1,1,1,8,11,0.727,2,8,10,4,3,2,4,4,45,37.5
    1985,10,10,11/15/1984,21,272,21.74469541,CHI,1,BOS,0,Big Loss,1,33,12,24,0.5,0,1,0,3,3,1,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,4,27,17.1
    1985,11,11,11/17/1984,21,274,21.75017112,CHI,1,PHI,0,Loss,1,44,4,17,0.235,0,0,,8,8,1,0,5,5,7,5,2,4,5,16,12.5
    1985,12,12,11/19/1984,21,276,21.75564682,CHI,1,IND,0,Loss,1,39,11,26,0.423,0,3,0,12,16,0.75,2,3,5,2,2,1,3,3,34,20.8
    1985,13,13,11/21/1984,21,278,21.76112252,CHI,0,MIL,0,Loss,1,42,11,22,0.5,0,0,,13,14,0.929,4,9,13,2,2,2,6,3,35,26.7
    1985,14,14,11/23/1984,21,280,21.76659822,CHI,0,SEA,1,Win,1,30,9,13,0.692,0,0,,5,6,0.833,0,4,4,3,4,1,4,4,23,19.5
    1985,15,15,11/24/1984,21,281,21.76933607,CHI,0,POR,0,Loss,1,41,10,24,0.417,0,1,0,10,10,1,3,3,6,8,3,1,4,4,30,23.9
```

Comment: please reduce the sample input to ~10-15 sample lines, we just need enough input lines to cover each of the requirements as well as a few lines that don't meet the requirements; also update the question with the expected result; if you know how to do it in `bash` then also update the question with your `bash` attempt (and the wrong output from your attempt if it does not match the expected output)

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso, I have reduced the input and inserted the output.

Comment: @markp-fuso see my "possible solution" in bash to this matter (not sure at all)

Comment: "the difference is higher than -20, the value should be replaced with "big loss". If it's between -19 and -5, ..."  But -19 and -5 are higher than -20 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- according to the sample data file the `Diff` column is field #12 (`$12`)
- if `Diff == 0` we'll assign a string of `Tie`

**Setup:** modified first data row to have `Diff == 0` in order to demonstrate the `Tie` test

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '                                             # do not include this line if placing in a script file (eg, script.awk)
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR>1 {      if ($12 <= -20) $12 = "Big Loss"
        else if ($12 <=  -5) $12 = "Loss"
        else if ($12 <=  -1) $12 = "Close Loss"
        else if ($12 <=   0) $12 = "Tie"
        else if ($12 <=   4) $12 = "Close Win"
        else if ($12 <=  19) $12 = "Win"
        else                 $12 = "Big Win"
      }
      { print }
' scores.dat                                      # do not include this line if placing in a script file (eg, script.awk)
```

Another `awk` idea using arrays to hold the boundary values and the associated replacement strings:

```
awk '                                             # do not include this line if placing in a script file (eg, script.awk)
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","
        n=split("-20,-5,-1,0,4,19,9999999",boundary,",")
          split("Big Loss,Loss,Close Loss,Tie,Close Win,Win,Big Win",replace,",")
      }
FNR>1 { for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
            if ($12 <= boundary[i]) {
               $12 = replace[i]
               break
            }
      }
      { print }
' scores.dat                                      # do not include this line if placing in a script file (eg, script.awk)
```

Both of these generate:

```
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc
1985,1,1,10/26/1984,21,252,21.6899384,CHI,1,WSB,1,Tie,1,40,5,16,0.313,0,0,,6,7,0.857,1,5,6,7,2,4,5,2,16,12.5
1985,2,2,10/27/1984,21,253,21.69267625,CHI,0,MIL,0,Close Loss,1,34,8,13,0.615,0,0,,5,5,1,3,2,5,5,2,1,3,4,21,19.4
1985,3,3,10/29/1984,21,255,21.69815195,CHI,1,MIL,1,Win,1,34,13,24,0.542,0,0,,11,13,0.846,2,2,4,5,6,2,3,4,37,32.9
1985,4,4,10/30/1984,21,256,21.7008898,CHI,0,KCK,1,Win,1,36,8,21,0.381,0,0,,9,9,1,2,2,4,5,3,1,6,5,25,14.7
1985,5,5,11/1/1984,21,258,21.7063655,CHI,0,DEN,0,Loss,1,33,7,15,0.467,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,2,5,5,1,1,2,4,17,13.2
1985,6,6,11/7/1984,21,264,21.72279261,CHI,0,DET,1,Close Win,1,27,9,19,0.474,0,0,,7,9,0.778,1,3,4,3,3,1,5,5,25,14.9
1985,7,7,11/8/1984,21,265,21.72553046,CHI,0,NYK,1,Win,1,33,15,22,0.682,0,0,,3,4,0.75,4,4,8,5,3,2,5,2,33,29.3
1985,8,8,11/10/1984,21,267,21.73100616,CHI,0,IND,1,Close Win,1,42,9,22,0.409,0,0,,9,12,0.75,2,7,9,4,2,5,3,4,27,21.2
1985,9,9,11/13/1984,21,270,21.73921971,CHI,1,SAS,1,Close Win,1,43,18,27,0.667,1,1,1,8,11,0.727,2,8,10,4,3,2,4,4,45,37.5
1985,10,10,11/15/1984,21,272,21.74469541,CHI,1,BOS,0,Big Loss,1,33,12,24,0.5,0,1,0,3,3,1,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,4,27,17.1
1985,11,11,11/17/1984,21,274,21.75017112,CHI,1,PHI,0,Loss,1,44,4,17,0.235,0,0,,8,8,1,0,5,5,7,5,2,4,5,16,12.5
1985,12,12,11/19/1984,21,276,21.75564682,CHI,1,IND,0,Loss,1,39,11,26,0.423,0,3,0,12,16,0.75,2,3,5,2,2,1,3,3,34,20.8
1985,13,13,11/21/1984,21,278,21.76112252,CHI,0,MIL,0,Loss,1,42,11,22,0.5,0,0,,13,14,0.929,4,9,13,2,2,2,6,3,35,26.7
1985,14,14,11/23/1984,21,280,21.76659822,CHI,0,SEA,1,Win,1,30,9,13,0.692,0,0,,5,6,0.833,0,4,4,3,4,1,4,4,23,19.5
1985,15,15,11/24/1984,21,281,21.76933607,CHI,0,POR,0,Loss,1,41,10,24,0.417,0,1,0,10,10,1,3,3,6,8,3,1,4,4,30,23.9
```

Comment: Hi, when I call the script there is no output. I observe there is no END block, is that correct?

Comment: Btw, I need to call the script with "gawk -f script.awk filename.csv"

Comment: there is no need for an `END{}` block since a) we're printing the lines as we process them and b) we are not storing anything in memory (eg, running counts/totals) so there's nothing we need to print (from memory) once we've processed all input lines; I've verified my input matches the input you've provided (placed in a file named `scores.dat` and then cut-n-pasted my answer into my environment ... and it generates the same output as listed above; have you verified your input file is just ascii characters with a comma delimiter (what does `file scores.dat` show)?

Comment: Please see my previous comment. I'm not calling it from the command line but from a script .awk and with  gawk -f script.awk filename.csv

Comment: placing the code in a script file (eg, `script.awk`) means you need to remove the 1st line (`awk '`) and last line (`' scores.dat`) from my answer; your script file should start with `BEGIN { FS=OFS="," ...` and end with `{ print }`